# How kill app thread and restart it?

Tags: android

I need to kill my app's all threads and restart the app. I have googled some ways, I used this way to kill the app. But I don't know how to restart 
my app.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Can you tell how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  Its very unlikely that you actually want to do this.

Comment: I want to use hot-fix, such as [Tinker](https://github.com/Tencent/tinker). When I download a patch,  I need restart the app to let the patch work.

Comment: You can use `recreate();`

Answer (score 0):

With a single process, you could schedule an alarm in the AlarmManager to open some activity/service/receiver in a few seconds, then kill the current process. However in the newer versions of Android you are not likely to have it fired exactly when you want (expect several minutes of delay).

Another option is to have a "restarter" service or receiver in a second process in your app that you would call just before killing the first process. Then the restarter service could wait a few seconds in a bg thread so that the first process dies, and then call some component (activity/receiver/service) in the first process to restart it again.